# React Native - RNPickerSelect - Empty value before the first dropdown item

Tags: typescript, react-native, selector, picker, react-native-picker-select

```
When I use RNPickerSelect I get my items in the dropdown, but right before the first one there is an empty value which I want to remove. I just want the first item to be selected automatically. Does anyone know how to solve this?
```

**The interface I use to declare the props and reuse them in the parent component**

```
interface AutoSuggestProps {
      types: IRequest[];
      onSelect: (item: string) => void;
      disabled: boolean;
      placeholderLabel: string;
      title: string;
      dropdownValue: string;
      setDropDownValue: (val: string) => void;
    }
```

**Here I am creating a component which uses the React Native component**

```
 export const DropdownList = ({
      currencyType,
      onSelect,
      disabled,
      placeholderLabel,
      title,
      dropdownValue,
      setDropDownValue,
    }: AutoSuggestProps): JSX.Element => {
      return (
    <View>
```

**I have used it like this because it was only way I could get at least the first item. But the problem is on top of the first item, there is an empty element that is selectable**

```
       <RNPickerSelect
    disabled={false}
    value={dropdownValue}
    onValueChange={el => {
      setDropdownValue(el);
      onSelect(el);
    }}
```

**If I use the placeholder like this `placeholder: {{value: dropdownvalue, label: dropdownvalue}}` , a label 'Select item is printed' which I don't want.**

```
  placeholder={{}}
    items={types}
    useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
    Icon={() => {
      return <DropdownArrowSVG_noFill width={(width + height) / 50} height={(width + height) / 50} fill={dropdownColor} />;
    }}
  />
</View>
)
})
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I aplogoise. I thought my edit was saved but it turns out it wasn't. Above is the edited answer. I have sepereated the code with comments